# Was Twain the first author to write of Zombies?

Tags: history-of-literature, mark-twain

Although the word is not used, Twain's zany novel of title-frenzy and mad-scientist capitalistic schemes *The American Claimant* (sequel to *The Gilded Age*) describes the intent by the megalomaniac Mulberry Sellers to "materialize" dead people for use as cheap labor. He intends to contract these would-be minions of his out as policemen and soldiers and such, thus saving city and national governments big money while reaping a giant profits for himself.

Is this 1892 novel the first to include "zombies" among its characters?

Actually, these "zombies" never really materialize - they remain figments of Mulberry's overfertile imagination; yet still, as far as the concept goes, is this the "advent of the zombies"?

If so, Twain was not only ahead of his time, again, but a case could be made that he foresaw the inroads that robots would make into the labor market (if you stretch or conflate "zombies" to "robots").

Comment: Is there any particular reason you think Twain's treatment might be the very first?

Comment: I'm not sure where the data dump of old Lit questions is, but [a similar question was asked on the first incarnation of Literature SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36859227#36859227).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Zombies go way back, further than 1892. There has been a fear of the undead since caveman times, when some tribes used to tie up corpses to stop them coming back to life.

Perhaps the earliest form of writing about living dead is [The epic of Gilgamesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh) (roughly 18th century BC)<sup>[[1](https://dawnoftheundead.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/the-history-of-zombies-in-literature-or-revenge-of-the-living-trope/)]</sup>:

> I will knock down the Gates of the Netherworld,
> I will smash the door posts, and leave the doors flat down,
> and will let the dead go up to eat the living!
> And the dead will outnumber the living!

Although [Ilmari Karonn](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/723/ilmari-karonen) mentions in the comments that that passage was probably copied from [The descent of Ishtar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishtar#Descent_into_the_underworld), which was around but not written.

The origin of the word 'zombie' comes from the Haitian 'zombi' - meaning spirit of the dead.<sup>[[2](http://umich.edu/%7Eengl415/zombies/zombie.html)]</sup>. Originated in roughly 1791 from the voodoo culture.

But the actual mention of the word 'zombie', the earliest I can find is [here on google books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gbhIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=zombi&hl=fr#v=onepage&q=zombi&f=false).

It is an account of Hispaniola in French by Moreau de Saint-Méry. It is called *Description topographique, physique, civile, politique et historique de la partie française de l'Isle Saint-Domingue* and was published in 1797:

> Une jeune beauté au teint d'ébène, qu'un conte de **Zombi** (*) fait trembler de tous ses membres, veille pour l'attendre, lui ouvre une porte qu'elle sait faire mouvoir sans bruit , & n'a qu'une crainte , c'est d'être trompée dans son attente.
>
> (*) Mot créol qui signifie: esprit, revenant.

Translated using google translate:

> A young ebony-skinned beauty, whom a Zombie (*) tale frightens to the bone, stays awake waiting for him, lets him in through a door that she knows how to open quietly, and has but one fear, which is that her wait was in vain.
>
> (*) Creole word meaning: spirit, undead.

Later of course we have [Frankenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein) (1818), which is arguably a zombie.

---

Sources.

<sup>[[1](https://dawnoftheundead.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/the-history-of-zombies-in-literature-or-revenge-of-the-living-trope/)]</sup> - Dawn of the undead - wordpress.com
<sup>[[2](http://umich.edu/%7Eengl415/zombies/zombie.html)]</sup> - Umich.edu

Comment: Zombie is a West African word. I don't think it's very nice to ignore the word's origins, and then pretend that the French were the first people to use the word.

Comment: @Hamlet I just added a whole thing on the origin literally as you said that. It came from Haiti

Comment: @Hamlet is it all right now? I didn't mean for it to come across as if I was trying to say the french made it up, I just meant the first mention is in a french piece of literature.

Comment: Oral literature counts as literature. Just because people don't write things down doesn't make their literature less important.

Comment: @Hamlet isn't the definition of literature 'written works'? I have mentioned this is as well, is there still a problem? :(

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: I'm offended that you didn't capitalize "French"; after all, I like French toast and French fries, not to mention French-cut green beans.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon oops :P Was that in comments or answer?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: comments; I didn't notice it in the answer; my beret is all poofy now from the smoke that poured out of my ears.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon *Je m'excuse beaucoup pour ma mauvaise utilisation de la langue et de bons noms*

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: J'accuse!

Comment: FWIW, the passage you cite from the Epic of Gilgamesh was probably copied from the [Descent of Ishtar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishtar#Descent_into_the_underworld), where it also appears and makes far more sense in context. (Ishtar is threatening to break down the gate of the underworld if the gatekeeper will not open it and let her enter.) However, while the tale itself is surely far older (being based on a Sumerian myth from c. 3000 BC), AFAICT the only known copies of the Descent of Ishtar are from c. 900 BC, so the line in Gilgamesh does seem to be the oldest known attestation.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen interesting and I might add something about that later if I have time to do some research

Answer (score 4):

Zombies are also found [elsewhere](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/2152/481) in Norse mythology; during [Ragnarök](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar%C3%B6k), the unworthy dead return from Hel to fight the Norse gods (and the [Einherjar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einherjar)).

I read about this recently in Neil Gaiman's *[Norse Mythology](http://www.neilgaiman.com/works/Books/Norse+Mythology/)*:

> Loki's troops are the legions of Hel. They are the uneasy dead, the
>   ones who died shameful deaths, who will return to the earth to fight
>   once more as walking corpses, determined to destroy anything that
>   still loves and lives above the earth.

<sup>Gaiman, Neil. "Ragnarok: The Final Destiny of the Gods." *Norse Mythology*. New York: W.W. Norton, 2017. p 272.</sup>

The Einherjar themselves might also be classified as zombies, because they also returned from the dead, but they don't really feel zombie-esque because they're on the home team.

> [...] and the Aesir and with them the Einherjar, all the warriors who
>   died good deaths in battle, will dress for war, and together they will
>   ride out to Vigrid, the final battlefield.

<sup>ibid., p 273.</sup>

I haven't read any other Norse mythology to date, so I take him at his word that he is faithful to the original myths. Wikipedia [cites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar%C3%B6k#cite_note-FOOTNOTEByock200572-33) a similar claim to Jesse Byock's [2005 translation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140447555) of *[Prose Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda)*.

This is not earlier than [Gilgamesh](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/2140/481), but as the *Prose Edda* was compiled circa 1220 CE (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda)), it's certainly earlier than Twain.

Comment: RE: accuracy: https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2017/02/the-politics-of-retelling-norse-mythology/517422/

Comment: "*Wikipedia cites a similar claim to Jesse Byock's 2005 translation of Prose Edda.*" - it seems like that Wikipedia page has been edited; your specific cite link no longer works, and I can't see any mention of the dead emerging to fight. But surely it must be easy to find free online retellings of Norse mythology which you can source this claim to.

Comment: Argh. I'll see if I can find a replacement citation next week, @Rand.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of revenants was definitely present in the [Mabinogion](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/2147/2892), which dates to the about the 12th century CE, and is present in Norse mythology in relation to [Freyja's powers](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/2444/2892).

As Beastly Gerbil suggests, this idea may be as old as literature itself.